# What's the difference between 工事 and 建設?

Tags: nuances

What's the difference between 工事 and 建設, especially in the context of 工事中 and 建設中?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

建設 only means creating a new building, house, tower, bridge, highway, tunnel, etc.

工事 has a much broader sense. It includes 建設, but it also refers to demolishing a building, renovating a house, laying an optic fiber cable, fixing a broken water supply pipe, installing an air conditioner, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the Japanese explanations if you’re interested in them:

> **建設** 
> 建物・施設を新しくつくること。
>  **工事** 
>  土木・建築などの作業。